# Bone constraint [x]transformation & Object [x]transformation

Tags: constraints

I am having trouble with xTransformation on Bone Constraint.
It is not behaving the way xTransformation on Object Constraint behaves.

**Object Constraint/ xTransformation works the way I want:**

The Target and Owner are Local Space.

While the Empty moves in it's **local space** on Y axis,
The Object rotates in it's **local space** on X axis.
When the Empty rotates in **Global space** -90o to it's right
and proceeds on X **Global axis** the Object still rotates on it's X **local space**.

-
**Bones Constraint/ xTransformation, unfortunately does not work the same:**

The Target and Owner are Local Space.

While Bone moves in it's **local space** on Z axis,
Bone.001 rotates in it's **local space** on Y axis.
But when the Bone rotates in **Global space** -90o to it's right
and proceeds on X **Global axis**, Bone.001 does not rotate on it's **local space** Y axis.

I added an example blend file that illustrates this problem, after opening the file press play.
https://pasteall.org/blend/cbe2279f05d149598bb892ea49502e7c

Help on getting the bones to react the same way it does for object, would be highly appreciated.

Gifs and Images:

As you can see the Sphere rotates when it moves to it's right
But the Bone.001 does not rotate when it moves to it's right
although the settings in xtransformation are the same as the Sphere.

[image]

These are the settings for the Sphere
[image]

These are the settings for the Bone.001
[image]

Comment: hello, you should be able to edit your question and put some pictures. You can also share your file (copy paste the link it will give): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you will do that